# Fetching a list of emails from ASPNetUser table given id from another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a list of id's from a profile table. In the profile table I have a reference back to the ASPNetUser table that holds the emails addresses for each user and I need to get each email address for the users that I have an id for from the profile table. I'm looking for an easy query for this.

So I have a list if ids from the profile table (1,2,3,4,5)

YogaProfile with ref back to AspNetUser table

```
   public class Profile
{

    [Key]
    public int YogaProfileId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(36)]
    [Index]
    public string ApplicationUserGuid { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this join but not sure how to include a list

```
List<string> emails = from s in dbContext.YogaProfiles
                                   join c in dbContext.Users
                                   on s.ApplicationUserGuid equals c.Id
                                   where s.YogaProfileId in (List of ids here)
                                    select c.Email).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Contains` method.

```
var ids = new List<int> { 1,2 };   
List<string> emails = (from s in dbContext.YogaProfiles
                                   join c in dbContext.Users
                                   on s.ApplicationUserGuid equals c.Id
                                   where ids.Contains(s.YogaProfileId)
                                    select c.Email).ToList();
```